# How to count no. of exact keyword occurance in one column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex, string

I'm looking for the solution to get no. of exact keyword occurrence in mysql column.

As this is needed for "multiple keyword search" functionality, there can be single or multiple keyword.

I found very good solution as below, but it count for no of containing keyword rather than count for Exact keyword.

```
SELECT 
in_member_id,
st_jsondata,    
ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(st_jsondata)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( st_jsondata, "John", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH("John")        
)
+
ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(st_jsondata)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( st_jsondata, "Seipelo", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH("Seipelo")        
)
AS count1 FROM tbl_member_master Having count1 > 0 ORDER BY count1 DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

What is problem with solution is it search for "John", "John123", JohnAb" etc. same for second keyword. I don't expect this way.

If I will get something like regular expression replace function, it worked for me.

Please do share if anybody having something related to this problem.

```
Search Keyword: sonal, khunt

Column Data:
ID | ColumnToSearch
1 | {'st_first_name':'sonal','st_last_name':'khunt'}
2 | {'st_first_name':'sonal105','st_last_name':'khunt105'}
3 | {'st_first_name':'sonal109','st_last_name':'khunt109'}
4 | {'st_first_name':'sonal','st_last_name':'patel'}


Expected Result:
ID | Count
1 | 2
2 | 0
3 | 0
4 | 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: your question is really bad formulated, maybe if you give us a table definition and sample data with expected results it will make it more clear.

Comment: I will suggest you not to fully depend on mysql, use php instead to count the words... This query will consume more memory and time, as well it will be laggy when large number of data is present in your db..

Answer (score 1):

You can add where filter using word boundaries of REGEXP to your query:

```
SELECT 
in_member_id,
st_jsondata,    
ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(st_jsondata)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( st_jsondata, "John", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH("John")        
)
+
ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(st_jsondata)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( st_jsondata, "Seipelo", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH("Seipelo")        
)
AS count1 FROM tbl_member_master WHERE st_jsondata REGEXP '[[:<:]](John|Seipelo)[[:>:]]' Having count1 > 0 ORDER BY count1 DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will only find those records with strings like `John` than `John123` and replaces.. so that you get the exact count.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. I have found this regular expression, but was trying to merge it with replace function.

Comment: Sorry, no regexp in `REPLACE()`.

Comment: @RickJames .. yes.. but what are you trying to say?

Comment: The solution here won't work.  Example:  `line with John and Johnson.` will incorrectly get a count of 2.  Hence the regexp is needed (but unavailable) in the replace call.

Comment: You are right.. but here.. OP is dealing with first names.. which are one words.. so.. whey will either be `John` or `Johnson`.. If it was not the case.. I would have suggested mysql udt functions.. :)

Comment: How about `Johnny Seipelo` ?  The count will be 2, but should be 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77545/discussion-between-karthik-manchala-and-rick-james).

Comment: @RickJames No because of where condition, johnson will be filtered out so you will get only 1 occurrence. The solution given is worked for me for exact keywords, even I have tested it well with different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed to have the apostrophes around the strings, then `'khunt'` instead of `khunt` in the 3 `LENGTH` calls.